# In WPF How do I give focus to a button in a list of buttons without clicking on that button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list

```
<ListBox Name="PageNumberListItemsControl" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
         ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyPanel}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountTemplate}" Grid.Column="1">
</ListBox>
```

A template to make a list of buttons

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CountTemplate">
    <Button Content="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

code to update the position in the list

```
PageNumberListItemsControl.SelectedIndex = CurrentPageNumber - 1;
```

I want the code selected button to be highlighted. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want that when the item is selected the button inside should be focused. So you can try adding some trigger like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CountTemplate">
  <Button Content="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click" Name="bt">  
  </Button>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="true">
       <Setter TargetName="bt" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" 
                               Value="{Binding ElementName=bt}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then when you click some item to select it or use code, the button inside will be automatically focused. However when you use arrow keys (up and down) to navigate through the listboxitems, the selected item still has focus. That behavior is in fact what we should keep, because only when the selected item still has focus, we can still use the up/down arrow key to ***continue navigating***. Otherwise if the button inside has focus, we cannot continue navigating using up/down arrow keys (unless you use some codebehind handling some key event).